# Shell scripting illegal number error

Tags: bash, scripting

I was checking whether a file exists or not but i get error with the following code

```
filename="a.txt"
if [ -s $filename ] ; then  
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

It gives the error [: 116: Illegal number

What could be the problem?

Comment: It gives [: 116: Illegal number:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `-f`:

```
filename="a.txt"
; touch $filename
; echo $filename
if [ -f "$filename" ] ; then  
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

`-s`is to check that "FILE exists and is a socket".

Notes:

- uncomment the `touch` sentence to ensure the file exists.
- uncomment the `echo $filename` sentence to ensure he var content.
- Try to enclose with `"` to ensure no space or special chars inside `$filename`.

References:

- [Man page for test](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test)

Comment: Are you sure no spaces or special chars on file name?

Comment: No its simply a.txt. Anyways i'll try to find another way.

Comment: Can post the full script? Or try to reduce the code to get a full testcase